# C++ CLI how to write a unmanaged struct using BinaryWriter

Tags: c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a structure that is shared between two unmanaged and managed(CLI) C++ projects.

```
struct FileHeader {
    uint16_t    a;
    uint16_t    b;
    uint32_t    c;
    uint32_t    d;
};
```

(I don't want to modify this structure to a managed one like i.e.)

```
[Serializable] 
ref struct FileHeader { ... };
```

***What I have so far:***

```
FileHeader fileHeader = { };

...

IntPtr ptr((void*)&fileHeader);  

array<Byte>^ buffer = gcnew array<Byte> (sizeof(FileHeader)); 

System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(ptr, buffer, 0, sizeof(FileHeader));

fileWriter->Write(buffer); // System::IO::BinaryWriter
```

Is there any other (better) way to write this structure data using **System::IO::BinaryWriter** ?